# Pandas Python: Delete Rows of DF That Have ASCII Letters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains, letters

I have a column in my dataframe that I would like to convert to datatype int. However it is throwing an error because some of the rows have letters in their entries. I would like to create a new dataframe that only has entries in this column with pure numeric entries (or at least no letters).

So my question is: Is there a way to do something like the following,

```
df=df[df['addzip'].str.contains("a")==False]
```

But with a list where the "a" is? See the example below,

```
df=df[df['addzip'].str.contains(list(str(string.ascii_lowercase)+str(string.ascii_uppercase)))==False]
```

I know that this very possible to do with an apply command but I would like to keep this as vectorized as possible so that is not what I am looking for. So far I haven't found any solutions anywhere else on stack overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a regular expression

```
df = df[~df['addzip'].str.contains("[a-zA-Z]").fillna(False)]
```

Comment: @Alex 

Excellent. This is exactly what I was looking for. :) Worked great.

I knew there had to be a  way to do this without resorting to an apply function. Thank you so much.